# Segmentation fault when reading text file to array of linked list

Tags: c, arrays, file-io, linked-list, singly-linked-list

The *read_to_list* function is designed to scan the contents of a file - *dump.txt* - and load it into the array of singly linked lists.

**The problem lies in LINE 2 of the main function: *read_to_list(argv[1]);***

The dump.txt file contains the following information:

```
Name        Group Size
----------------------------------
Anna         2
Bill         4
Connor       6
Denise       8
```

The argv[1] correlates to a text file that I declare on the command line to dump data from my linked list after running the program. After exiting the program the .txt file saves the data in the above format format.

I do not know why I am getting a segmentation fault when calling the *read_to_list* function on the file passed in the CLI as it appears to me that the function should load the data correctly and the function is called at the right position in the main function.

Thank you for any and all help that I can get!

The code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    char name[20];
    int size;
    struct node *next;
}node;

node* head[4]={NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL};
node* tail[4]={NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL};



void read_to_list(char *filename)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int mined_partysize;
    char mined_partyname[20];

    char header = "Name\t\tGroup Size\n----------------------------------\n";

    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        return;

    fseek(fp, strlen(header), SEEK_SET);
    printf("This is working1");
    while(fscanf(fp, "%s%d", mined_partyname, &mined_partysize) == 2)
    {
        printf("This is working2");
        if(mined_partysize == 0)
        {
            printf("\nThat is not a valid command. Party not added!\n");
        }
        if(mined_partysize >= 1 && mined_partysize <= 2)
        {
            add_party(0, mined_partyname, mined_partysize);
        }
        else if(mined_partysize >= 3 && mined_partysize <= 4)
        {
            add_party(1, mined_partyname, mined_partysize);
        }
        else if(mined_partysize >= 5 && mined_partysize <= 6)
        {
            add_party(2, mined_partyname, mined_partysize);
        }
        else if(mined_partysize >= 7)
        {
            add_party(3, mined_partyname, mined_partysize);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return;
}


//
// main function
//


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x;
    read_to_list(argv[1]);
    while (1)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\n\nEnter 1 to add a party\nEnter 2 to remove a party\nEnter 3 for the list of the party\nEnter 4 to change party size.\nEnter 5 to quit.\n\n");

        // user interface
        scanf("%d",&x);
        char name[20];
        int size;
        switch(x)
        {

            case 1:
                printf("\nParty Name: ");
                scanf("%s", name);
                printf("\nParty Size: ");
                scanf("%d", &size);
                if(size == 0)
                {
                    printf("\nThat is not a valid command. Party not added!\n");
                }
                if(size >= 1 && size <= 2)
                {
                    add_party(0, name, size);
                }
                else if(size >= 3 && size <= 4)
                {
                    add_party(1, name, size);
                }
                else if(size >= 5 && size <= 6)
                {
                    add_party(2, name, size);
                }
                else if(size >= 7)
                {
                    add_party(3, name, size);
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("\nSize of party to delete: ");
                scanf("%i", &size);
                delete_party(NULL, size);
                break;

            case 3:
                list_parties();
                break;

            case 4:
                change_partysize(name, size);
                break;

            case 5:
                write_to_file(argv[1]);
                exit(0);
                break;

            default:
                continue;
        }
    }
}


//
//add function
//


void add_party(int h, char *name, int size)
{
    //declare file pointer
    FILE *fp;

    //to be used by fscanf
    int number;

    //create a new node
    int i=0;
    int breaker = 0;
    node *p;
    node *new_item;

    new_item = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node)); // allocate memory the size of the struct

    strcpy(new_item->name,name);
    new_item->size = size;

    if(head[h] == NULL && tail[h] == NULL) // if an empty list, create a head and tail
    {
        head[h] = new_item;
        tail[h] = head[h];
        new_item->next = NULL;
        return;
    }

    //traversal
    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        p = head[i];
        while(p != NULL)
        {
            //check that no repeating names. delete nodes that do have repeating names
            if(strcmp(p->name,name) == 0)
            {
                printf("\nSorry, that name is already taken\n");
                free(new_item);
                return;
            }
            p = p->next; //go to the next node in the list
        }
    }
    tail[h]->next = new_item;
    new_item->next = NULL;
    tail[h] = new_item;


}
```

Comment: Where did it get to when you debugged it?

Comment: line 134: read_to_list(arg[1])

Comment: So step into `read_to_list`...

Comment: @John3136 here is the gdb output: 

(gdb) run ./a.out dump.txt

Starting program: /DCNFS/users/student/cbrereto/COEN11/a.out ./a.out dump.txt


Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7b7d921 in __strlen_sse2_pminub () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Comment: You need to learn to use gdb.. Try the bt command to get a stack trace.

Comment: `char header = "Name\t\tGroup Size\n----------------------------------\n";` ??

Answer (score 0):

You're de-referencing a null pointer.

Comment: are you referring to node *p=NULL; ??